# multitenancy using namespace api in Push Queue(GAE)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, multi-tenant

Was planning to use namespace API for multitenant support for our GAE application so was going through [namespace API documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/multitenancy/multitenancy#Python_Using_namespaces_with_the_Task_Queue/) which suggests push queues are supported in namespace API but doesn't quite explain how does namespacing works for push queues.

So ideally what we want is to push tasks in the queue-A and for each namespace get it processed separately. That is if in *queue-A* with *namespace-X* there are 100 tasks waiting and *namespace-Y* there are only 5 tasks then *namespace-Y's* tasks should not wait for completion of 100 tasks in namespace-x.

So for example:-

**queue name**- `queue-A`
**clients**- `client-X` & `client-Y`

now both client-X & client-Y are pushing into *queue-A* with namespace name as `X` and `Y` respectively. So what we expect from namespace is if there is a lot of worklog in queue-A for *client-X* that shouldn't affect *client-Y's* **task processing speed**.

Does this get handled automatically in namespace API as I think this is a very common scenario in multitenant applications if no anyway to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the namespace has any implication in the task scheduling logic. From the task queue example from the doc you mentioned you see that the namespace information is recovered only when the task is actually handled, when the scheduling logic is already completed.

But that's not too bad - for correct operation your app's scaling and queue configuration should normally be set to handle the maximum workload you expect (combined across all namespaces) anyways, in which case the impact of one particular tenant over another, if any, should be insignificant.

Comment: Thanks @dan-cornilescu in normal applications what you explained above will totally make sense but in our case, we are into data processing and using push queues to be an intermediate placeholder for events before they can be taken for processing and hence they would be in huge numbers for some clients and so can affect data processing of others. That's why it becomes little important for us to manage it beforehand.